# output html from php echo syntax?

Tags: php, html, syntax, echo

I have a php mailer script that outputs a message on a div above the form:

```
// Send the email.
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
// Set a 200 (okay) response code.
http_response_code(200);
echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
}
```

I'd like to add a style and line break to the echo, but currently this is outputting it with the tags instead of as code:

```
echo "<span>Thank You!</span><br />Your message has been sent.";
```

I also tried changing the double quotes to single quotes but that didn't work.

=====================

** EDIT SOLVED **

The reason it wasn't showing the html is because the data was being sent to a js app that had this:

```
// Set the message text.
if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
}
```

I replaced .text with .html as shown below:

```
// Set the message text.
if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).html(data.responseText);
}
```

Thanks all for the advice.

Comment: try to remove `http_response_code(200);` and try again

Comment: or you can make it with another way is to add this message in `session` and print it out in your view

Comment: Do you want to output response code  ?

Comment: And why the "http_response_code(200)" ? It is 200 by default, so you don't need that line.

Comment: Tried removing http_response_code(200); but the result was the same, tags showing. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry @midknyte what tags showing ?

Comment: Do you mean your html isn't rendered?  If you were to swap all that code for some simple html does that render?  It's quite normal to output html elements within an echo as you are doing under Php.

Comment: Yeah, the html isn't being rendered, it's showing the tags exactly as I wrote them instead of rendering them.

Comment: Is that the ONLY html you send to the browser? Do you also send `<html>` and `<body>` etc etc. A well formed web page?? Or just that one piece

Comment: Figured it out, posted issue above. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Changed .text to .html on the associated js file. See solution on the OP question.